# How to extract all hyperlink titles from big html string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got an HTML string as :var code; I want to extract all hyper link title values in this big string and place them in textarea. I tried the following but it never works. could any one tell me what i am doing wrong?

sample hyperlinks to look for(i want to extract mango,cherry,...) :

```
 <a href="/season/">mango</a>
 <a href="/season/">cherry</a>
```

my code string has blocks of data like below:

```
<div class="details">
    <div class="title">
      <a href="/season/">mango</a>
      <span class="type">3</span>
    </div>

  </div>
```

full code:

```
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://asite.com/getit.php/&callback=?', function(data){

    //$('#output').html(data.contents);

 var siteContents = data.contents;    

//writes to textarea 
 document.myform.outputtext.value = siteContents ;


var start = siteContents.indexOf('<ul class="list">');
var end = siteContents.indexOf('<ul class="pag">', start);
var code = siteContents.substring(start, end);
 document.myform2.outputtext2.value = code ;

 var pattern = /<a href="([^"]+?)">([^<]+?)<\/a>/gi;
    code = code.match(pattern);
    for (i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
        document.write($2<br />'));
    }

});

</script>
```

Comment: ummm, `$("a").each(function(){ // concatenate };`?

Comment: Since you know JQuery,why don't you try `$(".list a").each(function(){  //do some thing})`

Comment: should $.getJSON be used here to get html... would $.ajax yield better results?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to parse HTML with regex. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) has some more info on that topic.

Since this question is tagged as jQuery, you could try something like the following...

Make a jQuery object out of the returned HTML:

```
$markup = $(data.contents);
```

Find the anchors:

```
$anchors = $markup.find('a');
```

Get the text (or whatever attribute you want from it):

```
arrText = [];
$anchors.each(function() {
    arrText.push($(this).text());
});
```

Put result into textarea:

```
$textarea.val(arrText.join(','));
```

Comment: thanks all for reply. Zhihao i tried your solution no data in text area:$markup = $(code);
$anchors = $markup.find('a');
arrText = [];
$anchors.each(function() {
    arrText.push($(this).text());
});
myTextarea.value = arrText.join(',');
<td><textarea rows="7" cols="15" name="myTextarea" style="width: 99%;"></textarea></td>

Comment: @user1788736 I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by "no data in text area". From your question, I assumed the HTML you were getting in your response would be in `data.contents`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: zhihao data.contents is orginal html. but i made it shorter (code hold data i want to extract from)so i avoid non necessarily hyperlinks in orginal html code. so i want to exctract all hyperlink titles from "code" and palce them in textarea.

Comment: @user1788736 Thanks for the clarification. I don't understand what issue you're having now though. You mentioned "tried [my] solution no data in text area". What exactly is happening or not working? The solution I provided should provide a general guideline to how you can get the text inside the anchors from the HTML string of the response.

Answer (score 0):

To achive this jquery is the simplest solution, you can try below code

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var copiedTitle = $(this).html();
    var previous = $('#test').html();
    var newText = previous +"\n"+ copiedTitle;
        $('#test').html(newText);
        });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boraganesh/cvC4X/)